fastify routes do not resolve to variables (req.params empty)
i am trying to ge a small fastify (typescript and nodejs) server running.
fastify.get('/query_tile/:z/:x/:y', async (req, reply) => {
    const t0 = performance.now()

    const { z, x, y }: { z: string, x: string, y: string } = req.params;
    const useCache = req.query.useCache !== 'false'; // use cache by default
    // ......
})

which comes from the fastify doc.
the problem i am having is, that z,x,y are not defined:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts:54:11 - error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ z: string; x: string; y: string; }': z, x, y

54     const { z, x, y }: { z: string, x: string, y: string } = req.params;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app.ts:55:32 - error TS2339: Property 'useCache' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

55     const useCache = req.query.useCache !== 'false'; // use cache by default
                                  ~~~~~~~~

What am i doing wrong here?
